# How to update a url variable value?

Tags: php

How can I update a url variable value?
The url will look like that for example:

```
www.example.com/product.php?.........&page=1...........
```

I would like to change page value from 1 to 2, the reason that I typed dots instead of real url is since the url is dynamic and not static.

So how can I do that?how can I update and url variable value?

**EDIT**

I will refresh the page with the new value so the page will be re-filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
     $QUERY_STRING = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    echo  $QUERY_STRING =  str_replace('page=1', 'page=2',  $QUERY_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not control your browser. The user and/or Javascript does. This means, you can **not** update a specific variable in the URL. (This *variable* is also called a HTTP GET Parameter).

What you have are below options:

- Use an HTML form, with `action=""` & `method=GET`. Use hidden fields, with `name=page` and `value=<number>`.

  ```
  <form action="" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2" />

      <!-- Use PHP to echo out all other GET parameters into hidden form fields -->

      <input type="submit" value="click me to go to page 2"/>
  </form>
  ```
- Use Javascript: [Parse out the GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript), and modify it.

Comment: But I want to change the value from a link, and not after a submit button clicked.. because the page 1,2,3,4 are links.